# Is there any way to pass a javascript object from the source code to the system/browser clipboard?

Tags: javascript, json, clipboard

I'm listening to a `Ctrl-C` event and creating a `JSON`, I'll need this `JSON` in a different part of my application where I intend to use the `JSON` for a custom paste on `Ctrl-V`; but I don't have any reference here to the previous part, where the copy was done. Not even a global variable (long story).

Basically, these `Ctrl-C` and `Ctrl-V` events are supposed to copy and paste complex custom-made HTML elements, with their own events and keyframe animations, from one part of the application to the other. Working with the `JSON` is the only way to go.

I did some digging and came across questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript), but they only address the case of putting selected text on the clipboard. I'm looking for something which can put custom content on the clipboard of the system or the browser.

Is there any inbuilt method, or an external utility or plugin, that would help me achieve this?

Thanks.

EDIT: This copy-paste feature will be used on a website by users, not just developers. Therefore, we can't assume anything. Cookies won't work because cookies might be turned off. `localstorage` or `sessionstorage` won't work because the application may be open for different projects in different windows; and the user might want to copy from one window and paste into another.

Comment: you could always use `localstorage` or `sessionstorage` depending on the lifetime required. although this may not work in older browsers. and will mean the user cannot paste in content from external sources

Comment: @MartinGlennon: Nice idea, but the user may want to paste the content on a different tab open in a different Window.

Comment: @MartinGlennon: Going by casual research on console, it looks like localstorage works even with different windows. Thanks. I'll try with my actual requirement, and if it works, I'm willing to accept your answer (but you'll have to post it as an answer).

Comment: when i say external i mean not from a browser

Answer (score 0):

You could look in to cookies here using jQuery:

```
// You can seriaize the data as JSON, like this:
$.cookie("property-name", JSON.stringify($("#foo").data()));

// Get data from the cookie:
$("#foo").data(JSON.parse($.cookie("property-name")));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but using cookies isn't a dependable solution for me as the user might have turned her cookies off.

Answer (score 0):

you could always use localstorage or sessionstorage depending on the lifetime required. although this may not work in older browsers. and will mean the user cannot paste in content from external sources